# How to validate multiple emailaddress using regexp in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have multiple email addresses within a field and from the dataframe, I have to validate if the email address has `@ .com` and separated by a `;` delimiter.

```
a
-----------------------------------------------
sample@email.com;sample2@email.com
sample
sample@email.com
sample2@email.com;test2@email.,sample@email.com
```

**Expected output :**

```
a                                                 a_new
---------------------------------------------------------
sample@email.com;sample2@email.com                Valid
sample                                            Invalid
sample@email.com                                  Valid
sample2@email.com;test2@email.,sample@email.com   Invalid
```

The 2nd and fourth records are invalid because of `@` and `.com` are missing even for a single email address and for multiple email addresses `test2@email.,` -> `com` is missing along with a different delimiter.

I was able to pull out for a single email address test. Not sure how to test if there are multiple email addresses.

Comment: Show us the code you're using right now? One option for validating multiple addresses would be to split on `;` and then validate each of the resulting items.

Comment: @Santosh, you posted a brilliant question `pyspark/hive count using window function` but deleted. I have a solution. Let me know if you still need help and will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

For complexe email validation Regex you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression).

But if you want only to verify an email has the form `anything@anything.com`, you can use this simple regex `.+@.+\.com` and to check there is a list of emails separated by `;` use : `^(.+@.+\.com)(; .+@.+\.com)*$` with the function `rlike`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [
    ("sample@email.com;sample2@email.com",),
    ("sample",),
    ("sample@email.com",),
    ("sample2@email.com;test2@email.,sample@email.com ",)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["a"])

df1 = df.withColumn("a_new",
                    F.when(
                        F.col("a").rlike("^(.+@.+\\.com)(; .+@.+\\.com)*$"),
                        "Valid"
                    ).otherwise("Invalid")
                  )

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+------------------------------------------------+-------+
#|a                                               |a_new  |
#+------------------------------------------------+-------+
#|sample@email.com;sample2@email.com              |Valid  |
#|sample                                          |Invalid|
#|sample@email.com                                |Valid  |
#|sample2@email.com;test2@email.,sample@email.com |Invalid|
#+------------------------------------------------+-------+
```